# How can I create a ppa from command-line in launchpad

Tags: ppa, launchpad, launchpadlib

I succesfully created my ppa, and I can now create new packages using the web interface of launchpad.

I'm trying to backport some packages from ubuntu trusty to precise using the `backportpackage` shell command however I allways need to create the package before launching this command.

**Is there any way to create new ppa in my launchpad account from `bash` shell or python library `launchpadlib`?**